# Use CSS to set units to px (where no unit defined)

Tags: width

The problem: Old dinosaur working with outdated html/css styling. This dude managed to enter a whole bunch of input field sizes using 
`Style='width:80'` and similar. That's right, without any 'px' or anything.

Now this works satisfactorily in MSIE 10 and above as well as Chrome and Firefox, but unfortunately the interface also has to support MSIE 9 (I have not even dared to attempt MSIE 8....) and MSIE 9 really does not like this. Fields just seem to have some random/default length and everything looks horrendous.

Replacing all the instances of this is a task more daunting than coming back from the dead (a general replace will only be moderately useful) so the question is...

Is it possible to set "THE" unit in CSS so that it is applied to all fields that are missing one? Use of jQuery is OK, it is already jQueried up the wazoo so that's fine. But please tell me this is at all an available option... or I shall find myself going mad replacing 1000+ fields...

Comment: There is no definable "default unit" in CSS that would help you override the values with missing units. Better alert your family to your future home in the insane asylum.... :(

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Units must always be defined, except for value 0.

But it shouldn't be that daunting, surely a regexp or two will handle it?

Comment: @Irresistance If it's only widths you want, then most likely a simple `(width:\s*\d+)\s*[^p]` replaced with `$1px` might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

does file search and replace with sublime text like Style="width:(.*?)" with Style="width:$1px" work for you?